# Mass Import Users without sending new user notification

Tags: plugins, users

I need to import users via csv file. I see lots of plugins that do mass imports, but they all seem to send out new user emails to the new users. Since this is currently being set up on a dev site, I don't want to send out the new user emails.

Are there any plugins that import users without sending out new user notifications

Comment: Why don't you simply uncomment or delete the mass mail function in a plugin. Seems that you only need it onces.

Comment: Here is a simalar question - in progress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25071/importing-users-from-another-wordpress-site/62730#62730

Comment: Migrating WordPress users with their password is easily possible with this free [WordPress user import export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/) plugin by [WebToffee](https://www.webtoffee.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CSV User Import](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-user-import/) looks promising...looking through the plugin file, I don't see anything regarding registration emails.