# Importing users? From another wordpress site

Tags: users, import

Is there a way to import users from another wordpress site?

Both sites are new. I just don't want to go through the trouble of adding the same users profile information and password.

Comment: Migrating WordPress users with their password is easily possible with this free [WordPress user import export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/) plugin by [WebToffee](https://www.webtoffee.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two options (third if you find any plugins).

1. I think if you export data from one WP, the users are also copied. The drawback is that you have to import all the content as well.
2. The second option is to export the users from MySQL using PHPMyAdmin. Just export the user table. If you want to include privilidges as well, you have to export wp_usermeta as well.

Comment: have you done that before? if so has it worked out (re: #2)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work at all without moving user meta table, so it is needed in any case if doing DB move.

Comment: I've not tested - but exporting the tables in MySQL should work as long as export all tables that have dependency.

Comment: If the sites are NOT new (you have users on each site), this method will fail since user IDs will overwrite each other.